# App engine connected Android app

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gwt

Problem with the new App engine connected android application projects for the google eclipse plugin? This is the "Big Daddy" sample shown at goolge i/o 2011. My sample project compiles and the android app appears to work fine and registers with the server. However when I send a message from the server I get the following: Having issue with sample project. Android appears to work fine and registers with the server and the c2dm server, however I cannot send a message.

Also of note on the server is a c2dmconfig datastore object. It has fields for authToken and c2dmUrl. The authToken has a token, however the c2dmUrl is NULL. I suspect this is where my problem lies, but not sure how to fix it.

Thanks Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this question by wondering the same thing, if the c2dmUrl being null is a problem. It would seem that this is not an issue though. If you look at the C2DMConfig (the entity that you are referencing), there is a function called "getC2DMUrl". Here it is:

```
public String getC2DMUrl() {
  if (c2dmUrl == null) {
  return DATAMESSAGING_SEND_ENDPOINT;
} else {
  return c2dmUrl;
}
```

So null is a supported value for this. If a specific URL isn't specified, it simply returns it to the default.

Comment: Got point there.  I moved on from the Big Daddy sample and wrote my own implementation of C2DM and it is working fine.  Thanks for the input though.